# How does Spring "magically" know which Bean type to use?

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring 5, I was puzzled as to how exactly the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` "magically" knows to use the correct implementation of my interface, since the references are to the interface not the implementing class.

#### Illustration

**Note**: Irrelevant code such as imports and unrelated behaviour has been ommitted

An interface `CleaningTool` and two implementing classes `Broom` and `VacuumCleaner`, with variations on the interface's method `doCleanJob()`

```
public interface CleaningTool {
    void doCleanJob();
}
```

```
public class Broom implements CleaningTool {
    @Override
    public void doCleanJob() {
        System.out.println("Sweep sweep sweep");
    }
}
```

```
public class VacuumCleaner implements CleaningTool {
    @Override
    public void doCleanJob() {
        System.out.println("Zoom zoom zoom");
    }
}
```

Then, my `AnnotationConfigApplicationContex` uses my class `AppConfig` thusly:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public CleaningTool broom(){
        return new Broom();
    }

    @Bean
    public CleaningTool vacuum(){
        return new VacuumCleaner();
    }
}
```

Finally, in my `MainApp` class, where I invoke the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`'s  `getBean()` method, is where I tested this puzzling phenomenon which I, at first, expected not to work:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        CleaningTool vacuum = ctx.getBean(VacuumCleaner.class);
        vacuum.doCleanJob();

    }
}
```

Console output: `Zoom zoom zoom`

Even though my reference types in both my `AppConfig` and `MainApp` were `CleaningTool`, Spring somehow knew to seek out the Bean that matched the class `VacuumCleaner.class`, in such a way that the `VacuumCleaner`'s behaviour was used.

How does this "magic" work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Configuration` is meant to provide a tool to define beans.
Spring creates these beans (instances of classes) and stores them in the ApplicationContext.

You can think of the Application Context as a map that contains mapping between ids / classes of actual beans to the actual instances of corresponding singletons.

So when spring starts it creates both `Broom` and `VacuumCleaner` and places both of these beans into application context.

Then the application context is "ready" and you call the following line:

```
CleaningTool vacuum = ctx.getBean(VacuumCleaner.class);
```

Note, that you don't ask for the interface `CleaningTool` but for concrete class `VacuumCleaner`. In this case spring goes to its internal mappings and just retrieves the value (actual object) by concrete class. No magic here :)

Comment: Great answer! Some clarification about my puzzlement: it's the fact that the Bean annotated methods in the Application Contect (in this example) return a `CleaningTool` interface, rather than a concrete class - is that something you could elucidate, perhaps? Thank you so much

Comment: Actually it doesn't really matter, we all prefer to "program to interfaces rather than to concrete types" but in this case spring will know anyway that these are the beans. After all it calls these methods of `@Configuration` and gets the real objects...